# VS code Python attach remote error 'connect ECONNREFUSED'

Tags: python, django, docker, visual-studio-code, ptvs

So I have this Django app inside of Docker running and I'm trying to attach VS code to it so I can debug here is my launch file

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Remote Attach",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "attach",
            "port": 8800,
            "host": "192.168.99.100",
            "pathMappings": [
                {
                    "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
                    "remoteRoot": "."
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Here's my docker file

```
FROM registry.gitlab.com/datadrivendiscovery/images/primitives:ubuntu-bionic-python36-v2020.1.9

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN mkdir /bbml

WORKDIR /bbml
COPY requirements.txt /bbml/
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN pip install ptvsd
ADD . /bbml/

CMD python -m ptvsd --host 0.0.0.0 --port 3500 --wait --multiprocess -m ./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8800
# CMD [ "python", "./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8800" ]
```

here's my docker-compose

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: "python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8800"
    container_name: bbml
    volumes:
      - .:/bbml
    ports:
      - "8800:8800"
      - "3500:3500"
```

As you can see I'm running ptvsd on port 3500, but everytime I push the green run button on VScode I get "connect ECONNREFUSE 192.168.99.100:3500". Any suggestions?

I was following this guide:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b78Tg-YmJZI

Comment: You don't want ptvsd, you want [debugpy](https://pypi.org/project/debugpy/).

Comment: @BrettCannon why's that?

Comment: Because ptvsd is no longer supported and debugpy is the new debugger.

Answer (score 5):

I also had this problem. I found the solution [here](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/707#issuecomment-664759340)

basically, you have to configure the debugger with `debugpy.listen(("0.0.0.0", 5678))`

This happens because by default debugpy is listening on localhost. if you have your docker container on another host you have to add `0.0.0.0`

Answer (score 1):

For me it was that the port I tried to use wasn't open on the remote machine:

```
sudo ufw allow <portNumber>
```

Comment: This helped slove the problem. Thanks!